# notserializable exception when trying to serialize java map converted from scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a method to serialize a java map `Map<UUID,String>`. It works fine. I can serialize and deserialize in java.

But I have to call this method from scala and this is my calling code.

```
def customSerialize:Unit = {
Serializer.serialize(modMap(scalaMap))

def modMap(oldMap : Map[UUID,SomeObject]) : java.util.Map[UUID,java.lang.String] = {
        oldMap map { case(k,v) => (k->v.name)}
}
```

The scala map is `scala.collection.Map` and I am using `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` for doing the conversion.

When I run this code I get the error

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.collection.JavaConversions$MapWrapper
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
```

It looks like I need one more conversion from `javaconversions$MapWrapper` to `java.util.Map`. Is this correct? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: for now I am adding a extra conversion method inside my java code where I iterate through the Map provided by scala and create a new Java Map out of it. I hope there is a better way to do this.

Comment: This is still a problem, so I opened an issue: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8911

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you do need to copy the map because the MapWrapper is not serializable.  Best would be for Scala to support this, but in the meantime a reasonable syntax is just to use the copy constructor for a java Map.  Your call would then look like this:

```
Serializer.serialize(new java.util.HashMap(modMap(scalaMap)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd open an enhancement issue requesting that these wrappers be serializable. Not that it would help you in the short term, but...

Have you tried the stuff in `JavaConverters` instead?